# Displaying data from two different model in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject.web.mvc

I am a newbie learning ASP.NET MVC from book.I am using NInject to Implement IoC. I have created a data model for Job and Location as below

**Table Name - JobDetails**

```
JobId<PK>
LocationId<FK>
JobName
```

**Table Name - Location**

```
LocationId<PK>
LocationName
```

I have created Entities for Location and JobDetails as Below

**JobDetails**

```
public class JobDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int JOBID { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    public string JOBNAME { get; set; }
}
```

**Location**

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationID{ get; set; }

    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have my Abstract and Context Class for Job Details and Location as below

```
public interface IJobDetails
{
    IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetailsInterface { get; }
}


public interface ILocation
{

    IEnumerable<Location> locationInterface { get; }
} 

public class EFLocationRepository : ILocation
{
    public  EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Location> locationInterface
    {
        get { return context.Location; }
    }
}

public class EFJobRepository : IJobDetails
{
    public EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetailsInterface
    {
        get { return context.JobDetails; }
    }
}
```

My Model class for Job and Location are as below

```
public class JobListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetails { get; set; }
}

public class LocationListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Location> Location { get; set; }
}
```

In my JobDetail Controller I want to display the location name instead of Location Id.
My JobDetail controller is as below

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    public IJobDetails repository;

    public JobController(IJobDetails job)
    {
        repository = job;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.jobDetailsInterface);
    }

}
```

How to display Location Name instead of Location id in my Job View?

N.B-I am learning MVC from Adam Freeman book and trying to create something new.Please let me know what I have done is correct or not.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? If so, you should be able to access the LocationName through the job repository like `repository.jobDetailsInterface.Location.LocationName`.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework,But i am not able to access the locationName thru jobDetailsInterface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to sleeyuen's response. You may want to add a "navigation" property to `JobDetails` model, like below:

```
public class JobDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int JOBID { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    public string JOBNAME { get; set; }

    public virtual Location JobLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to access Location name from view by doing: `repository.jobDetailsInterface.JobLocation.LocationName`

In your scenario I believe entity framework will be able to infer relationships from the model structure, so you won't need entity configuration set up

Please note, this approach leads to [N+1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/08/18/select-n1-problem-how-to-decrease-your-orm-performance/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The solution works for me.I didnt understood how i will be facing N+1 problem,Since I have 1-1 relationship between JOb and location model.Can you elaborate?

Comment: I believe it would lead to N+1 because, when calling ```repository.jobDetailsInterface;``` entity framework will not load ```JobLocation``` property. ```JobLocation``` gets loaded as a separate sql query from when we try to access the ```LocationName``` property from the view (known as Lazy loading). A fix would be use ```repository.jobDetailsInterface.Include(j => j.JobLocation)``` which will make sure entity framework eagerly loads the navigation property, more on this [at msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations @Varinder